# Как на C# запустить программу в определенное время

Tags: c#

Задача в следующем, как реализовать алгоритм, чтобы при запуске компьютера запускалась программа в фоновом режиме, а затем к примеру в 12:00, произвелись некоторые действия, и программа продолжила работать в фоне. Спасибо вам

Comment: @Николай Мартынов, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Для запуска выполнения каких-то задач по расписанию попробуйте [вот эту библиотеку](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/). Она  бесплатна, довольно гибка в настройке и вполне себе удобна. Можно, впрочем, попробовать написать этот функционал самостоятельно, но первый вариант будет куда проще. Самый простой (и неэффективный) вариант сделать это самому - повесить таймер, который ежесекундно будет проверять, наступил ли момент запуска задачи и в случае наступления запускать эту задачу.

Что касается атозапуска самого приложения, то самый очевидный вариант - это занести соответствующую запись в реестр Windows:

```
var  key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@
   "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\",true);

key.SetValue("myKey", "Путь к файлу, который нужно запустить");
key.Close();
```

Впрочем, для этого, по всей вероятности, могут потребоваться права администратора. Как с этим бороться, можете прочесть [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562350/requested-registry-access-is-not-allowed)

Comment: Спасибо буду разбираться, в автозагрузку сделал , вот хочу поковырять библиотеку